# How to store file/responses if user does not have SDcard?

Tags: android, storage, sd-card, android-sdcard

I have written code which saves a user's answers as well as a recorded audio piece (.3gp) to their SDcard, which then gets uploaded to a server. I know this probably is not the best way to go about this because a user may not have an SDcard. I know I can put code in to check to see if the user has an SDcard but that wont help much. Is there an alternative way to store info or files on a device which doesnt have an sdcard or better way to go about this? Thanks for the help!

EDIT: Code below was working solution

```
try{
File pathCacheDir = getCacheDir();
System.out.println("Got the Cache directory");
File newCacheFile = new File(pathCacheDir, cacheFileName);
newCacheFile.createNewFile();
FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream (newCacheFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to create a database for your app and store the file in a [blob](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/sql/Blob.html).

Answer (score 0):

The normal way is to hold large files on server, with your application loading them when needed. Economize the memory! :-)

Comment: The files are created by the user though. There is no need to downlaod anything from a server. For example the user fills out a questionaire and then that is sent to the server...I guess I could create a database on the server and then POST their answers to the database?

Comment: Exactly. If user creates and gets files, of course, DB is the best way. But if you use DB on server, user can use your application with internet ON only. I am afraid, more users would rather use SD than pay for the net. Or, if you are doing some greater project, you can support BOTH db on server and on the card.

Answer (score 0):

You should store some temporary data in the row folder of the project.

```
if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState()
                                            .equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
                                            cacheDir = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                                                            "LazyList");
                                        else
                                            cacheDir = Login.this.getCacheDir();
                                        if (!cacheDir.exists())
                                            cacheDir.mkdirs();
                                        File f = new File(cacheDir,"profileimage.jpg");
                                        try 
                                        {
                                            InputStream is = new URL(userImageurl).openStream();
                                            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
                                            Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
                                            os.close();
                                        } catch (Exception ex) 
                                        {
                                        }
```

Read care fully my above code in this code i have sore a picture file in the row folder of the project then upload to server.

I hope this is help.

Comment: Could you explain more? Did you mean the raw folder?

Comment: Please show my answer i have edited for more clarity in my answer.